# Issue while installing mongodb 3.2 version on CentOS 7.7

Tags: mongodb, installation, centos7

I have updated the repo file as below

```
[mongodb-org-3.2]
name=MongoDB 3.2 Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.2.asc
```

I am trying to install mongodb 3.2 on a CentOS 7.7 machine and facing below issues

```
Processing Conflict: mongodb-database-tools-100.2.1-1.x86_64 conflicts mongodb-org-tools <= 4.3.2
 --> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: mongodb-database-tools conflicts with mongodb-org-tools-3.2.1-1.el7.x86_64
```

Here is complete log [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXfQC.png)

Can you please help me resolving it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all packages of the other version(s) you have installed.

Comment: I have not installed any other packages of the other version.  Could you please guide me what command need to be run to remove all other packages.

Comment: Thanks D,   Command worked for me  "yum erase mongodb-database-tools"